# usage of neither A nor B

Tags: usage

> *With neither anywhere to return to nor anybody to greet him, ~*

I used 'neither A nor B' to express that 'he' doesn't have any place to go back and anybody to greet him.

Does the sentence above make sense?

Answer (score 1):

> With neither anywhere to return to, nor anybody to greet him.

is the same as saying

> With nowhere to return to, and nobody to greet him.

You're using this correctly.